# How should domain classes be designed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to present an example and some requirements and want to understand what the best domain model should should.

The DB is:

```
One Country has Many Cities.
One City has many Towns
```

Both tables have Id column.

In my C#, I have

```
public class Country
{
  public List<City> Cities {get;set;}
  public int Id;
}

public class City
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int CountryId {get;set;}
}
```

1. When I want to update a City, I can just take the Id of the country
   and update it. So this design works.
2. When I want to insert a new
       City, I can take city object and insert it in Db. So this design
       works.
3. When I want to delete a city, I take the Id of city and
           delete it from Db. So this design works.
4. When I want to show a city,
       I also need country column in the grid in UI so this design doesn't work.

I would then get country of each city from the country id column and that's painful.

If I had Country has a property of City class then I would have to create Country object for all city objects and I don't need the country object during update, insert and delete - I just need CountryId.

So my question is:

- How should I design them?
- Should I create a CountryName property in
  City class?
- Should I try another approach that you recommend?

Comment: That's why it is recommended to have separate set of model and view-model classes; model classes that map to the way you have things setup in the database and view-model classes that map to the way you have your view setup.

Comment: Are you working with a relational database or some other kind of database, or is everything in memory?

Comment: i am working with database. in view model, should i retrieve every model's related entity from Db? i currently am using viewmodel based on top of model classes. and the problem is that i have to get  Country name for every city object, which means i have to call a different select query that has country name column and that also means that the models are created by first creating city and then creating country objects for the city.

Answer (score 1):

*If I had Country has a property of City class then I would have to create Country object for all city objects and I don't need the country object during update, insert and delete - I just need CountryId.*

What's wrong with filling a `Country` object in all the `City` objects? They don 't need to be populated, you can simply store the IDs. This is known as lazy-loading in the ORM world (and possibly outside too).

For example:

```
public class Country
{
    private List<City> _cities;

    public int Id { get;set; }
    public IEnumerable<City> Cities
    {
        get
        {
            // load on demand
            if (_cities == null)
                _cities = LoadCities(Id);

            return _cities;
        }
    }
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public Country Country { get;set; } 
}
```

It boils down to which side of the relationship is in control. Is the country responsible for updating all its children (a cascading update), or do you just want the City to do it? Either way, holding a Country object is a lot less database-centric than having IDs floating around.

If you are performing a join between the Cities and Countries table (instead of LoadCities) then you'll have each city's country id anyway, and be pre-fetching the data.

Comment: lazy loading to get country for a city to load some properties now and some later... are you sure

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker it was just an example, I wouldn't do it like that. Chunky is better than chatty with databases, so joining the whole lot would be far better in this example. But for updating your City, you should still stick with using having a Country object rather than just an Id. You can then lazy load that if you want, based on its ID.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker by the way, NHibernate and the 1001 other ORMs generally do all this for you, if you want to spend more of your time writing the UI and business logic

Comment: Wouldn't this cause problems if you tried to serialize either of these objects? It creates a circular reference.

Comment: plus i am then dependent on the orm. i want to use stored procs so i am fine with creating jobs and retrieving all infromation but just for visualisng the results, i will have to add class properties... there must be a trick, may be by just adding id and name columns of related entity

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker you do keep the IDs. If you want to represent your model in a true OO fasion, then City should contain a Country/ParentCountry. As I mentioned above, maybe not very clearly, each of these can be an empty Country object with just its ID populated. How you load this initially is up to you. Dapper http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ would save you all this trouble

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a backreference to the Country object from City? that way, if you need the country's name you can just do:

```
string countryname = city.Country.Name;
```

This is how an ORM like entity framework would design it by default